# Undefined variable errors - strange situation

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade, laravel-5.5

I have a problem with existing project. 
I get the message:

> ErrorException (E_ERROR) Undefined variable: errors

and in my code where error occur is:

```
@if (count($errors) > 0)
```

I was try to install new project with same plugins and features and on new project I don't have that problem and error exception. 
Also I can't change that file, because it's plugins file.

Environment on both projects are:
LEMP,
PHP: 7.1.1
Laravel: 5.5

What can be that error?

Comment: Where do you have $errors defined? Where are you calling it from?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undef)

Comment: You're probably not defining $errors beforehand. Some environments will throw the error, some will log it silently, or not at all.

Comment: Well the error message you get is very clear? It doesnt know the variable errors. Check if the $error variable is set.  `if(isset($error){}`

Comment: it's not problem in variable it's problem in project. On one project I don't have that notice on second I have. I'm using laravel voyager admin panel. 
I can't modify that file because that's the plugin.

Comment: Is the web middleware applied to that route?

Comment: No, it's admin.user middleware in Voyager files.

Comment: `$errors` is usually sent when `ShareErrorsFromSession` middleware is set to run. If you don't run the middleware then you need to set the errors variable manually.

Comment: Thanks for answer but I want to know why I have on one project that error and don't have on other. Also, I can't change middleware, it's in the vendor folder...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My team was solved this error by uncomment ShareErrorsFromSession in app/Http/Kernel.php file

```
\Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
```

Answer (score 0):

Where have you created the route?

Inside of the `web.php` file, try to create your routes within the

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    //routes here
}
```

statement.

You may need to clear the route cache too 
`php artisan route:cache`

From the docs:  https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/middleware

> Out of the box, Laravel comes with web and api middleware groups that
>   contains common middleware you may want to apply to your web UI and
>   API routes:
>
> ```
> /**
>  * The application's route middleware groups.
>  *
>  * @var array
>  */
> protected $middlewareGroups = [
>     'web' => [
>         \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
>         \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
>         \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
>         \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
>         \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
>         \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
>     ],
>
>     'api' => [
>         'throttle:60,1',
>         'auth:api',
>     ],
> ];
> ```

Comment: I wasn't create that route. I'm using voyager admin panel and he was generate route file for his routes.

Comment: I wasn't create that route. I'm using voyager admin panel and he was generate route file for his routes.

In web.php I was just register that route:

    Voyager::routes();


Also I was add that route in web.php in web middleware group as you say but I that is not solved my problem. 

As a temporary solution I was set in AppServiceProvider in boot method: 


    error_reporting(E_ALL);

Comment: Have you reported the issue to the maintainer of Voyager?

Comment: No I was not because when I create new laravel project and install Voyager, everything works perfect, without that error.